# How to use 'categorical slot' in form in rasa 3.x?

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

I was trying to use 'categorical slot' in form in rasa 3.x but its not working as per the rasa 2.x 'categorical slot' . How to use 'categorical slot' in 'rasa 3.x' in correct way?
I was using 'categorical slot' in rasa 3.x as below screenshot

```
main_menu:
    type: categorical
    values:
      - shop_with_us
      - call_us
    mappings:
    - type: from_text
      conditions:
      - active_loop: user_details_form
        requested_slot: main_menu
```